# Python nested dictionary lookup with default values

Tags: python, dictionary, default-value, lookup

```
>>> d2
{'egg': 3, 'ham': {'grill': 4, 'fry': 6, 'bake': 5}, 'spam': 2}
>>> d2.get('spamx',99)
99
>>> d2.get('ham')['fry']
6
```

I want to get value of fry inside of ham, if not, get value, 99 or 88 as the 2nd example. But how?

Answer (score 19):

```
d2.get('ham', {}).get('fry', 88)
```

I would probably break it down into several statements in real life.

```
ham = d2.get('ham', {})
fry = ham.get('fry', 88)
```

Comment: rather `d2.get('ham', {}).get('fry', 99)`, not ? (DRY!)

Comment: Making something readable != repeating yourself. Repeating yourself would be to write a function to get ham's fry, and then another function to get spam's fry, when both functions could be written as one function which takes ham/spam as a parameter.

Comment: @Jesse, The previous version had two references to 'fry' and two references to the magic number being returned. The suggestion was a distinct improvement.

Comment: I'm not seeing that version anywhere.

Comment: @Jesse, odd. Neither am I. It took me about 3 or 4 edits to get this right, but SO seems to have collapsed it into 1, making me look far more decisive than I am.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I think if the edits are clustered within a certain window of time, they are collapsed.

Comment: Note: This breaks if `d2.get('ham'...` returns something that is not a dict (if `d2['ham']` was `'other'` say)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this a lot, you can write a helper function

```
def get_nested(d, list_of_keys, default):
    for k in list_of_keys:
        if k not in d: 
            return default
        d=d[k]
    return d

print get_nested(d2,['ham','spam'],99)
print get_nested(d2,['ham','grill'],99)
```

Comment: Feels like reduce. `functools.reduce(lambda d,x: d[x] if x in d else default, ['ham','spam'], d2)`

Comment: @KennyTM, That raises a `TypeError` for `['bacon','spam']`

Answer (score 4):

For the default values of get to work correctly the first default needs to be a dictionary, so that you can chain the .get calls correctly if the first fails.

```
d.get('ham',{}).get('fry',88)
```

you could also use a try, except block

```
def get_ham_fry()
  try:
    return d['ham']['fry']
  except AttributeError,e:
    return 88
```

Comment: String indexing will raise either a `KeyError` if no key is found, or a `TypeError` if the item doesn't support string indexing. I think `AttributeError` is only appropriate for the `get` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for dealing with nested dictionaries:

```
def get(root, *keys):
    """
    Returns root[k_1][k_2]...[k_n] if all k_1, ..., k_n are valid keys/indices. 
    Returns None otherwise
    """
    if not keys:
        return root
    if keys[0] not in root:
        return None
    if keys[0] in root:
        return get(root[keys[0]], *keys[1:])
```

Usage:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3}}
>>> get(d, 'b', 'c')
3
>>> get(d. 'key that's not in d')
None
>>> get(d)
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution for the issue could be:

from 'ham' get 'fry' else return 88

```
result = d2['ham'].get('fry', 88)
```