# Fastest way to get specific key from a dict if it is found

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am currently writing a scraper that reads from an API that contains a JSON. By doing response.json() it would return a dict where we could easily use the e.g `response["object"]`to get the value we want as I assume that converts it to a dict. The current mock data looks like this:

```
data = {
    'id': 336461,
    'thumbnail': '/images/product/123456?trim&h=80',
    'variants': None,
    'name': 'Testing',
    'data': {
        'Videoutgång': {
            'Typ av gränssnitt': {
                'name': 'Typ av gränssnitt',
                'value': 'PCI Test'
            }
        }
    },
    'stock': {
        'web': 0,
        'supplier': None,
        'displayCap': '50',
        '1': 0,
        'orders': {
            'CL': {
                'ordered': -10,
                'status': 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am looking after is that the API sometimes does contain "orders -> CL" but sometime doesn't . That means that both happy path and unhappy path is what I am looking for which is the fastest way to get a data from a dict.

I have currently done something like this:

```
data = {
    'id': 336461,
    'thumbnail': '/images/product/123456?trim&h=80',
    'variants': None,
    'name': 'Testing',
    'data': {
        'Videoutgång': {
            'Typ av gränssnitt': {
                'name': 'Typ av gränssnitt',
                'value': 'PCI Test'
            }
        }
    },
    'stock': {
        'web': 0,
        'supplier': None,
        'displayCap': '50',
        '1': 0,
        'orders': {
            'CL': {
                'ordered': -10,
                'status': 1
            }
        }
    }
}

if (
        "stock" in data
        and "orders" in data["stock"]
        and "CL" in data["stock"]["orders"]
        and "status" in data["stock"]["orders"]["CL"]
        and data["stock"]["orders"]["CL"]["status"]
):
    print(f'{data["stock"]["orders"]["CL"]["status"]}: {data["stock"]["orders"]["CL"]["ordered"]}')
```

> 1: -10

However my question is that I would like to know which is the fastest way to get the data from a dict if it is in the dict?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437708/python-nested-dictionary-lookup-with-default-values

Comment: You might be confusing "fast" with "readable". [PEP 505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) would introduce a handy null-coalescing operator. While it does not arrive, what exactly are the keys that you might not get in one `data` object? It seems like some of the checks you are making aren't really necessary.

Comment: @CarlosMenezes Hi! Well in my case that would be that I want to know  if there is any value for the key `status`. If it does then I would like to print out both `status & ordered` but in some scenarios the `orders {...}` is not in the API. E.g. if you remove the `'orders': {
            'CL': {
                'ordered': -10,
                'status': 1
            }
        }` from the data that would be one example of how the API could look like as well.

Comment: Finding any key from a dictionary in python already has O(1) time complexity. I don't think so there is any specific fastest way of doing it.

Comment: @HritikSingh what I was thinking more was that there is different scenarios that I could think of. e.g. using for loop to go through the api to see if it contains, try except, .get() etc etc... - and I would like to know which is the fastest when it comes for my question where I would liek to know which way is the fastest to get the value from given key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookups are faster in dictionaries because Python implements them using `hash tables`.
If we explain the difference by `Big O` concepts, `dictionaries` have constant time complexity, `O(1)`. This is another approach using `.get()` method as well:

```
data = {
    'id': 336461,
    'thumbnail': '/images/product/123456?trim&h=80',
    'variants': None,
    'name': 'Testing',
    'data': {
        'Videoutgång': {
            'Typ av gränssnitt': {
                'name': 'Typ av gränssnitt',
                'value': 'PCI Test'
            }
        }
    },
    'stock': {
        'web': 0,
        'supplier': None,
        'displayCap': '50',
        '1': 0,
        'orders': {
            'CL': {
                'ordered': -10,
                'status': 1
            }
            
        }
    }
}
if (data.get('stock', {}).get('orders', {}).get('CL')):
    print(f'{data["stock"]["orders"]["CL"]["status"]}: {data["stock"]["orders"]["CL"]["ordered"]}')
```

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-lookups-in-python-1d7503e9cd38) is a nice writeup on lookups in Python with `list` and `dictionary` as example.

Comment: Hi! In that case wouldn't it be better to put the if statement as walrus  `if found_data := data.get('stock', {}).get('orders', {}).get('CL'):` and then you could just do `found_data["status"]: found_data["ordered"]` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter how you extract it, it will O(1), you can use any of the approach you want.

Answer (score 1):

I got your point. For this question, since your stock has just 4 values it is hard to say if `.get()` method will work faster than using a loop or not. If your dictionary would have more items then certainly `.get()` would have worked much faster but since there are few keys, using loop will not make much difference.

Comment: Doing dictionary look-ups is ***O(1)*** meaning the amount of time it takes is independent of how many items there are. The will almost *always* be faster than anything involving a user-written loop because it's implemented internally in C or whatever underlying language the interpreter is written in.